# CSS Particles Js Overlap Issue

Tags: css

Here is the repository for my personal website: https://github.com/flakpanzer40/flakpanzer40.github.io

As you may notice, the particles I've used are simply showing below my name, image, and description. I've tried numerous times to overlap them so that the particles happen in the back, but to no avail. I've tried absolute positions, z-index, re-arranging the DIVs, etc. I'm terrible at CSS.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Please add following styles:

```
.container {
    /*other css*/
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.particles-js-canvas-el {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="particles-js" style="">   
    <canvas class="particles-js-canvas-el" width="1903" height="952" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;"></canvas>
    <div class="container">        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/EvanRen.jpg" alt="Evan Ren" style="width:500px;height:600px;border:5px solid white;border-radius: 50%;">
                <div class="intro-text">
                    <span class="name">University of Waterloo Computer Science</span>
                    <hr class="star-light">
                    <span class="skills">Problem_solving expert - Hardworking - Passionate</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#particles-js {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #13717c;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}
```

It is important that the parent (`#particles-js`) has `position: relative` so that you can use absolute positioning for the children.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I've added the above, however I'm guessing I take the "particles-js-canvas-el" from the other guy's answer? I've updated my files, but seems like im still doing something wrong(the particles and everything simply disappeared)